# Additional windows of an application open in wrong display

Tags: display, microsoft-windows

I'm using elementary os with a dual display setup. Following is the arrangement. 
[image]
Let's say there's a Firefox window opened in the bottom screen. Then we click on some link and another Firefox window pops up. It's supposed to pop in the same screen where I click the link and where the Firefox window originally is. But instead it appears in the upper display.

How to fix this. This is really annoying. I'm doing web application development and I have my IDE opened in the upper display and browser windows supposed be in the bottom window. It's easy when do debugging. But because of this issue it simply is not posible.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of main display is the one which is with the white start in it. It's possible to choose any display as the main display by clicking on the star. This is hard to miss. But I missed it somehow. Hope this will help somebody.